# PDF: Remove all text boxes containing a specific text

Tags: pdf

Say the following text box has been added to the bottom of all of the pages of a PDF document:

> This text has been added at time ‘t’

where ‘t’ is variable.

Is there any method to delete all those text boxes at once?